# $_SESSION variable doesn't set

Tags: php, session, xampp

This is my code while i am trying to fetch data from local server by using $_SESSION id variable. In thiss page I am getting the error :

```
<?php
$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPaasword = "";
$dbName = "ridobiko";

$con = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPaasword, $dbName) or die(mysqli_error($con));
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
}

$bike_id = $_SESSION['id'];

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><b>Bike Brand</b></tr>
            <tr><b>Bike Name</b></tr>
            <tr><b>Bike Image</b></tr>
            <tr><b>Bike rent price</b></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM bike_details WHERE bike_id = '$bike_id';";
            $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query);
            echo "
                <td>".$row['bike_brand']."</td>
                <td>".$row['bike_name']."</td>
                <td><img src='".$row['bike_image']."' height='100' width='100'></td>
                <td>".$row['bike_price']."</td>
            ";
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Although I set the $_SESSION variable on previous page. In this page I was connected with the local server and through this page I amstoring my details in the local server and storing the $_SESSION variable value :

```
if($total_accounts>0){
    echo "
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('Bike details alreay exists');
            window.location='question1.php';
        </script>
    ";
}

else {
    $filename = $_FILES["bike_image"]["name"];
    $tempname = $_FILES["bike_image"]["tmp_name"];
    $foldername = "bike_image/".$filename;
    move_uploaded_file($tempname, $foldername); 
    $query = "INSERT INTO bike_details (bike_brand,bike_name,bike_price,bike_image) VALUES ('$bike_brand', '$bike_name', '$bike_price', '$foldername');";
    $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    
    $_SESSION['id'] = $bike_id;
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
    echo "
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('Bike details updated successfully');
            window.location='question2.php';
        </script>
    ";

}
```

Here is the Error I am geeting while running the code:

```
Bike BrandBike NameBike ImageBike rent price
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ridobiko_question1\question2.php on line 56

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ridobiko_question1\question2.php on line 57

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ridobiko_question1\question2.php on line 58

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ridobiko_question1\question2.php on line 59
```

Comment: Please do not post code as picture

Comment: @executable will you check it on once more, I edited my question. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

*Any page* that needs to access `$_SESSION` should *start with*:

```
<?php
session_start();
/* other code... */

/* don't do this: 
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
*/
?>
```

or you will get unwanted results. Also, if you want to check if you have *already* set a value into session, this is how you test it:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["someVar"])) {
  $_SESSION["someVar"] = "defaultValue";
  /** any default values you want **/
}

/* now you can continue with $_SESSION["someVar"] where is needed */
?>
```

You should apply these changes, then retry.